# [three.js][editor] CesiumMan can't walk

Tags: animation, three.js, editor

I imported a gltf(CesiumMan) which contains animations.It will walk if everything is ok.However, nothing happened when I add script and run.
  Here is my script:

```
console.log(this);
var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this);
var animations = editor.animations[this.uuid];
if(animations) {
    animations.forEach((clip)=> {
        mixer.clipAction( clip ).play();
    });
}
function update( event ) {
    mixer.update(event.delta);
}
```

or take a look at this picture:
[runtime Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jYRB.png)

Comment: Already answered here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/cesiumman-cant-walk-when-using-the-editor/5287/2